# SQL / Python - String replacement pattern with commas

Tags: python, sql, regex, string

I need to achieve the following task using **preferably SQL** string functions (i.e CHARINDEX, LEFT, TRIM, etc) or Python.

Here's the problem:

```
Example string: BOB 3A, ALICE 6M

Required output: 3aB, 6mA
```

As you can see I need to get the last two characters for each word preceding a comma, then append the first character of each item to the end. Preferably this should work for any number of items with commas separating them but the likely case is two.

Any hints / direction would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Python solution:

```
def thesplit(s):
    result = []

    for each in s.split(', '):
        name, chars = each.split(' ')
        result.append(chars.lower() + name[0])

    return ', '.join(result)
```

You can use it like this: `thesplit('BOB 3A, ALICE 6M')`

Answer (score 0):

Yoyu may try this,

```
>>> s = "number: 123456789"
>>> ', '.join([i[-2]+i[-1].lower()+i[0] for i in s.split(', ')])
'3aB, 6mA'
```

Comment: or `', '.join(i[-2]+i[-1].lower()+i[0] for i in s.split(', '))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = 'BOB 3A, ALICE 6M'

print ', '.join( map( lambda x: x[-2:].lower()+x[0], str.split(", ")  )   )
```